# The image is shifted when convert 8bpp to 24bpp

Tags: c#, image, graphics

When i used following code to convert a bitmap from 8bpp to 24bpp, the resulted image is shifted but i can't figure out the reason of that, can anyone help?

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(Bitmap bmpIn)
{
    bmpIn.Save(@"F:\sara1.bmp");
    Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
    {
         // Prevent DPI conversion
         g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
         // Draw the image
         g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
         // g.DrawImage(bmpIn, 0, 0);
    }
    converted.Save(@"F:\sara2.bmp");
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: DrawImageUnscaled() doesn't do what everybody expects it to do.  Use the DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload instead.

Comment: Should that first bmpIn.Save be a bmpIn.Load?

Comment: @HansPassant: Does that mean you could also solve it by setting the Graphics objects DpiX/DpiY to the Image's HorizontalResolution/VerticalResolution or vice versa?

Comment: No, these properties don't have setters.

Comment: @HansPassant I tired to use g.DrawImage(bmpIn, 0, 0); but i didnt work i dont know the reason of the problem! and why changing the number of bits per pixel will affect the spatial resolution?

Comment: I made this because i can't get the graphics from an 8bpp image

Comment: That's because you didn't use the DrawImage() overload that uses a Rectangle.

Comment: @SaraSaeed your code is working for me correctly without any change. It is causing no shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have problem in `bmpIn` before receiving it in your function.
You can test following (better) code after putting your 8bpp image in `f:\sara1.bmp` (just to ensure that you have 8bpp image not shifted before conversion).

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(Bitmap bmpIn)
{
    //Bitmap bmpIn;
    bmpIn = new Bitmap(@"f:\sara1.bmp");
    Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
    {
         g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
         Rectangle rng = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bmpIn.Size);
         g.DrawImage(bmpIn, rng);  // use this instead of following
    }
    converted.Save(@"F:\sara2.bmp");
}
```

Hope it works fine 4 u. I used DrawImage(Image img, Rectangle rng) as you are already told in comments

Answer is complete. Following is explanation. Your code (edited. Use it as it is and follow the comment)

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(Bitmap bmpIn)
{
    bmpIn.Save(@"F:\sara1.bmp");
    return;
    // After you have called this function. Go open your image f:\sara1.bmp from
    //hrad disk-- I doubt you would find it shifted here even before conversion
    Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
    {
         // Prevent DPI conversion
         g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
         // Draw the image
         g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
         // g.DrawImage(bmpIn, 0, 0);
    }
    converted.Save(@"F:\sara2.bmp");
}
```

Again Your code ( I just ignored your received 8bpp Bitmap and fetched it directly from f drive, supposing that you would put it before running the application or at least before calling this function)

Following code also worked fine for me.

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(Bitmap bmpIn)
{
    Bitmap bmpIn = new Bitmap(@"f:\sara1.bmp");
    Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
    {
         // Prevent DPI conversion
         g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
         // Draw the image
         g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
         // g.DrawImage(bmpIn, 0, 0);
    }
    converted.Save(@"F:\sara2.bmp");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me:

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(Bitmap bmpIn)
{
    bmpIn.Save(@"F:\sara1.bmp");
    Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
    {
        // Prevent DPI conversion
        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        // Draw the image
        // g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
        g.DrawImage(bmpIn, 0, 0, converted.Width, converted.Height);
    }
    converted.Save(@"F:\sara2.bmp");
}
```

Providing the width and height rescales the image.